# Django silently discarding uploaded files with long paths

Tags: parsing, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I am having an issue where Django Rest Framework appears to be silently discarding uploaded files with long paths.

Here is my view class and post method:

```
class UploadMediaViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    parser_classes = [parser.MultiPartParser]

    # POST /api/upload/media/
    def create(self, request):
        LOG.info(f"************** request.FILES = {request.FILES}")
```

The form data that is sent is as follows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryBEDAIwXzG6Ik2xVY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="transactionId"

804d4146-0947-4d96-90b5-8ffbbc0b2135
------WebKitFormBoundaryBEDAIwXzG6Ik2xVY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="oOJGp433ODZvBOZTCXNz1oO7ogG0j3BRRBo98jpx1iIlvMPeNoc8nBKvpoTjx9PsOl5ulGGWniur3TdbDSd9TpgsnWhhqurcQO3TnssSQNHWti7xm7nZGW6tFRtrjrvwoJm9Bds5AsMcNKxT7oBkzA35fA1fgo5jkiUAfHHiduMdGIYf3NJGk8LP54JAORfYEK05mdHdQ4zfpMKfDUNJLnc5tk3H/AndroidLandscape.mp4"; filename="oOJGp433ODZvBOZTCXNz1oO7ogG0j3BRRBo98jpx1iIlvMPeNoc8nBKvpoTjx9PsOl5ulGGWniur3TdbDSd9TpgsnWhhqurcQO3TnssSQNHWti7xm7nZGW6tFRtrjrvwoJm9Bds5AsMcNKxT7oBkzA35fA1fgo5jkiUAfHHiduMdGIYf3NJGk8LP54JAORfYEK05mdHdQ4zfpMKfDUNJLnc5tk3H/AndroidLandscape.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryBEDAIwXzG6Ik2xVY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="oOJGp433ODZvBOZTCXNz1oO7ogG0j3BRRBo98jpx1iIlvMPeNoc8nBKvpoTjx9PsOl5ulGGWniur3TdbDSd9TpgsnWhhqurcQO3TnssSQNHWti7xm7nZGW6tFRtrjrvwoJm9Bds5AsMcNKxT7oBkzA35fA1fgo5jkiUAfHHiduMdGIYf3NJGk8LP54JAORfYEK05mdHdQ4zfpMKfDUNJLnc5tk3H/Yym32tTMGQAfAMVGFTUJA1z9zQB3YremlDV1Hluotwj21UZWP9Aop6QTPvUMVIZVS8Hk6gADadVu4TihPloTy5N7JX99SgPqf3JZILRSMtEMCXLeT4gw34aq5e0HfxetOlKHTx6m2uS1SLFHi8OvcujtWEIAlTfXQW5pvsFGMJYOwNwWjncOoZETXaTs1LspDUHchPEHypp4CHEM5Y3e5HhsKBkA9cFJs6oA26XQW7y/AndroidPortrait.mp4"; filename="oOJGp433ODZvBOZTCXNz1oO7ogG0j3BRRBo98jpx1iIlvMPeNoc8nBKvpoTjx9PsOl5ulGGWniur3TdbDSd9TpgsnWhhqurcQO3TnssSQNHWti7xm7nZGW6tFRtrjrvwoJm9Bds5AsMcNKxT7oBkzA35fA1fgo5jkiUAfHHiduMdGIYf3NJGk8LP54JAORfYEK05mdHdQ4zfpMKfDUNJLnc5tk3H/Yym32tTMGQAfAMVGFTUJA1z9zQB3YremlDV1Hluotwj21UZWP9Aop6QTPvUMVIZVS8Hk6gADadVu4TihPloTy5N7JX99SgPqf3JZILRSMtEMCXLeT4gw34aq5e0HfxetOlKHTx6m2uS1SLFHi8OvcujtWEIAlTfXQW5pvsFGMJYOwNwWjncOoZETXaTs1LspDUHchPEHypp4CHEM5Y3e5HhsKBkA9cFJs6oA26XQW7y/AndroidPortrait.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryBEDAIwXzG6Ik2xVY--
```

When my create() method receives the request, I find that request.FILES contains only the first file (AndroidLandscape.mp4).  The second file (AndroidPortrait.mp4) seems to be silently discarded.

I suspect that this is being done by parser.MultiPartParser, but I'm not sure.

Is it being discarded because the path is too long?

(Update: I did some testing, and 470 characters seems to be the magic path length limit. If the path is 471 characters or longer, the file is NOT included in request.FILES)

If upload paths cannot be that long, I can accept that, but I need to detect that this has happened so that I can return an appropriate error response to the client, instead of silently discarding files. If so, how can I detect that in my method?

Comment: What I can see by comparing with [a w3c example](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) :
(1) Can you try to remove the "name" part ? It doesn't seems to be necessary with filename attribute.
(2) "Content-Disposition" should have the value "file" for videos, with "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" i think.
(3) The multipart declaration is missing ("Content-Type: multipart/mixed;"). --
Any a this point can push the parser to consider it as a "malformed part" ; but you are right, it should Not be ignored silently :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out why this is happening. The Django Rest Framework's multi-part form header parser has the maximum header length hard coded at 1024 bytes.  With a long file path, the size of the header is too long, and the MultiPartParser stops reading from  the stream after 1024 bytes.  This results in the header being invalid, and the file is discarded.  Unfortunately, this "overflow" is silently swallowed, and thus the file is silently discarded, leaving no way for the developer's code to even know that it happened, or that the file was even attempted to be uploaded.

I was able to implement a working solution by subclassing/overriding the affected classes, copy/pasting the library code for the affected methods, and finally changing the hard coded 1024 byte limit to a higher number.

It's not a great solution, because patching library code is brittle, and the solution could cause conflicts in future versions of DRF, but that's the only solution that I see at this point.

If anyone wants to implement this solution, the code with the hard coded limit is this:

in .../site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, stream, boundary):
        self._stream = stream
        self._separator = b'--' + boundary

    def __iter__(self):
        boundarystream = InterBoundaryIter(self._stream, self._separator)
        for sub_stream in boundarystream:
            # Iterate over each part
            yield parse_boundary_stream(sub_stream, 1024)
```

The 1024 in the last line must be increased to the desired max header length.